# How do you code MIPS special instructions using GCC 4.9.2

Tags: gcc, mips

I am using a MIPS 64 bit processor that has a CRC32 instruction (not part of the standard instruction set). It's OP Code is b011100. Is there a straight forward way to use this instruction in the **asm** directive using GCC 4.9.2 without hacking the compile?

Comment: Just to be sure, your cross-compiled version of GCC doesn't directly support that command in inline assembler and there is no intrinsic that can call it directly?

Comment: That's correct - the chip vendor supports an older (4.6) compiler but we are using some newer packages that require, among other things, C++11 atomics and some 4.9 specifics.

Comment: Can you put the code that uses the CRC instruction into one .c file and compile that with the vendor's compiler, then link the resulting .o file with the rest of your code using the 4.9 compiler? (Using .c linkage to avoid name mangling issues.)

Comment: Yuck.  Here's hoping someone has something better than using a 'db' statement and dropping the opcode directly into an inline stream of instructions.

Comment: I think I'll try Markgz's version first. That will be a lot more readable if it works. Fall back will be the  Yuck db  method.

Answer (score 1):

My best thought here is to create an inline assembler function that does a define byte statement for that opcode and returns the value in a standard C/C++ manner - basically write your own intrinsic function for it.  At least then the hack is isolated to 1 location in the code and can be replaced in the future if your vendor sends you newer code that rectifies this problem.

I would also be complaining to your vendor about this oversight as well. :)